# Batch upload multiple photos to multiple user accounts

Tags: facebook-graph-api, batch-processing

I have an array that looks as follows:

```
$userImages = array(
    '100000000000001' => array(
        '..../image01.jpg',
        '..../image02.jpg',
        '..../image03.jpg',
    ),
    '100000000000002' => array(
        '..../image04.jpg',
        '..../image05.jpg',
        '..../image06.jpg',
    ),
);
```

which contains FB user ids as keys, and then an array of images to upload to each users account.

My upload code looks as follows:

```
/** @var FacebookSessionPersistence $facebook */
$facebook = $this->container->get('fos_facebook.api');
$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);

$count = 1;

foreach ($userImages as $userId => $images) {
    $batch = array();
    $params = array();
    foreach ($images as $image) {
        $request = array(
            'method' => 'post',
            'relative_url' => "{$userId}/photos",
            'attached_files' => "file{$count}",
            'access_token' => $this->getUserAccessToken($userId)
        );
        $batch[] = json_encode($request);
        $params["file{$count}"] = '@' . realpath($image);
        $count++;
    }
}
$params['batch'] = '[' . implode(',', $batch) . ']';

$result = $facebook->api('/', 'post', $params);
return $result;
```

I've added user access tokens to each image, under **access_token**, but when $facebook-api() is called, I get the following back from Facebook:

[image]

Does anyone know why, I'm getting these errors? Am I adding the user access token in the wrong place?

Comment: When doing single image uploads, the process works perfectly, so I do have the required permissions granted.

Comment: It seems you can't upload to multiple user accounts in one batch. I moved the access token to the root of the $params object, and the images uploaded successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The access_token had to be added to the $params associative array, in the root, not to each image item!

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is good, but you need to put the access token inside the body for every individual request.

For example:

```
...
$request = array(
  'method' => 'post',
  'relative_url' => "{$userId}/photos",
  'attached_files' => "file{$count}",
  'body' => "access_token={$this->getUserAccessToken($userId)}",
);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone know why, I'm getting these errors? Am I adding the user access token in the wrong place?

Have you made sure, you’ve *actually* added access tokens at all, and not perhaps just a `null` value?

The error message does not say that you used a *wrong* or *expired* user access token, but it says that a *user* access token is required.

So I’m guessing, because you did not really put actual tokens into your separate batch request parts in the first place, *then* the fallback to your app access token occurs, and hence that particular error message.

Comment: I was trying to add the user access tokens to the individual image upload items, and it turns out, it doesn't work that way. When I added a user access token to the root of the $params, the upload went successfully, but this means I can't upload to multiple accounts in one batch process, so it seems.